# Include Bootstrap in a PHP application

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning PHP / HTML / CSS. Today I want use Bootsrap.

I use a basic HTML5 template called index.php In this file I want include a footer like this:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ressources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ressources/css/style.css">
    <script type='text/javascript' src="ressources/script/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="ressources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrap">
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
    
    <?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

But I dont see my footer in my page. I just put an "Hello World" in my footer.php

Comment: let us see your footer.php file

Comment: Oh god, Wamp wasn't started. Now I've an error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''includes/footer.php'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\GV\index.php on line 41"

Comment: Resolved, thanks Tyler.

Comment: @TylerCollins There is no difference using include as a statement vs a function. Both methods are identical as include is a language construct, syntax does not influence behavior.

Comment: except it looks goofy in certain contexts.

Comment: @TylerCollins Exactly. But at that point it is a stylistic preference, not a functional difference.